# Linux UART (16550A) RS485 mode

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart, flow-control, rs485

I'm trying to configure my serial port (/dev/ttyS0) to automatically control RTS pin. I already can do it from user space by ioctl TIOCM_RTS flag toggling but it's too slow in my case - slave device respond too fast and I miss it.

I tried to achieve it by enabling RS485 mode but I end with bellow error:

```
    unable to set IOCTL:: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

My implementation

```
  port_fd = open(port.c_str(), O_RDWR);
if (port_fd != -1) {
  struct serial_rs485 rs485conf={0};
  rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_ENABLED;
  rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND;
  rs485conf.delay_rts_before_send = 0;
  int rv = ioctl(port_fd,TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf);

  if(rv){

      printf("rv = %d\n", rv);

      perror("unable to set IOCTL:");

}
```

dmesq output:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.338716] 00:01: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.359441] 00:02: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.380168] 00:03: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 7, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.400953] 00:04: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.421677] 00:05: ttyS4 at I/O 0x2f0 (irq = 7, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.442338] 00:06: ttyS5 at I/O 0x2e0 (irq = 7, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

How can I force my serial port to work in this mode or maybe there is another way to achieve RTS automatic control?

OS:

```
4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I think you need 16650 for RS485 mode